# Is this a current or voltage divider circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, amplifier

[image]

What is the configuration of Rx and Ry?
Is it a current, voltage divider or neither?

Comment: This sounds like homework. Please show some attempt at reasoning one way or the other.

Comment: In the title you ask about the whole circuit, then in the question you ask about Rx and Ry, that is confusing! Also -1 for lack of **thinking** effort.

Comment: Closing due to being homework without any effort shown.

Answer (score 3):

Just redraw it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnNzhLm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hmm. Looks a lot like a voltage divider to me.

Answer (score 2):

What? It is neither (unless you want to be perverse and describe gain as upside-down division). It is a non-inverting voltage amplifier - i.e. a voltage MULTIPLIER.

HINT: the amplifer will do everything it can to keep the voltages at the + and - terminals the same. The rest you can figure out from there. (The output approximates to an ideal voltage source, again as constrained by the physical abilities of the silicon.)

Comment: OP specifically asked: *What is the configuration of Rx and Ry?* and that **is** a voltage divider.

Comment: yes, but the title of the thread ...

Comment: I agree, the title does not match the actual question in the text. If you look at it carefully, OP asked **two** questions, you answered the first.

Comment: looks rather as if the OP got a h/w and doesn't want to think it out him/herself ... or even formulate the question properly. probably the prof was trying to get them to see a non-inverting amp as an upside down divider, which is reasonable.

Comment: Sure, why **think** when there's Stack Exchange EE ? ;-)

Comment: This is the answer. I was about to post the same until I saw it had already been done. Nobody would look at a non-inverting amp and think “voltage divider”. The OP just didn’t state his question properly.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is a voltage divider. Typically, the output of an operational amplifier has very low output impedance which lends itself to act as a voltage source, thus the output voltage \$V_{out}\$ gets divided across \$R_x\$ and \$R_y\$.

Comment: There is a clearly labeled node called "Vin" and we would expect Vout to be Vin divided by something if this was a divider. It isn't - unless you want to look at it in a very misleading and confusing way. The right answer is "neither".

Comment: @dmb (from vout to v-) Rx and Ry are there to provide a sample of the output voltage via voltage division. (from vout to vin) Now, the relationship of output to input is obviously not a divider. The conclusion, the question title doesn't match the actual question =] and I agree with one of your comments, the real question was probably about the output to input relationship of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit is nothing else than one of the various control systems with negative feedback. The forward (open-loop) gain is Aol - and a part "k"  of the output signal (using a simple passive resistive **voltage divider**) is fed back to the inverting input node.

This results in a closed-loop transfer function

**Acl=Aol/(1+k*Aol))**  .